# accessing the selected value from filter_select or sharedData object crosstalk R

Tags: r, crosstalk

I want to be able to use the selected value from a crosstalk::filter_select in the title of a plot that is based on the sharedData.  Here is a minimal example of what I am after (except instead of "x" in the title it is the filtered value).

```
library(crosstalk)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

shared_mtcars <- SharedData$new(mtcars)

plt <- ggplot(shared_mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(title=paste("Weight vs. MPG for", "x", "cylinder cars."))

bscols(widths = c(3,NA),
       list(
         crosstalk::filter_select("cyl", "Cylinders", shared_mtcars, ~cyl, multiple = FALSE)
       ),
      ggplotly(plt)
)
```

Comment: did you manage to make it?